# Firebase dynamic link not working with Testflight IOS

Tags: firebase, testflight, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using Firebase Dynamic Links, which have been working just fine when the app is installed directly to my phone via Xcode. However, when I use the copy on Testflight (same version as local build), the dynamic link does not open in the app. Instead I get redirected to a webpage in Safari that asks me if I want to 'Open link in app?' After I hit open, I get an error in Safari that says "Safari cannot open the page. The error was: 'The URL can't be shown.'" Anyone know why I can't open the dynamic link in the Testflight app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I had the same problem. Have a look at your associated domains (Xcode build settings) for all configurations and make sure they match Firebase.
Mine had a wrong one for DevRelease configuration(which is TestFlight)

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I had my associated domains in Debug only, and it was missing in release.